# open whitelist file error on Android

Tags: android

My app throws alot of error message as below but I don't know what it means. It's just a single line, no more information.

> 10-11 13:43:47.697: E/IBINDER_HOOK(17121): open whitelist file error
>
> 10-11 13:43:47.697: E/IBINDER_HOOK(17121): open whitelist file error
>
> 10-11 13:43:47.697: E/IBINDER_HOOK(17121): open whitelist file error
>
> 10-11 13:43:47.697: E/IBINDER_HOOK(17121): open whitelist file error
>
> 10-11 13:43:47.697: E/IBINDER_HOOK(17121): open whitelist file error
>
> 10-11 13:43:47.697: E/IBINDER_HOOK(17121): open whitelist file error

UPDATE: This error showns on Lenovo P700 (I just tested my app on this device)

Comment: What device? Can you reproduce on the emulator?

Comment: Did some googling and I don't think it is related to your app. Kill your app and look for the message in the log. Could it be a Lenovo bug?

Comment: Yes, I run the app on Lenovo phone.

Answer (score 2):

just touch one file as /data/data/whitelist

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem like yours. I dont know whether it's similar or not. But when I looked at the error log, I found other error such "cannot convert JsonObject to Json array"(in my condition, i want to convert it, but I got the wrong way). When i solve that error(convert JsonObject to JSonArray) there's no open whitelist file error.